# How to create a new list and tag nodes in it using xslt

Tags: list, xslt

I am transforming an XML to another using Identity Transformation and during this, based on a condition I want to tag few nodes in a new list.
Suppose, I have an XML like:

 <nod>
        
     <a>A</a> 
        
        <b>B</b>
        
        <c><p>p1</p></c>
        
        <c><p>p2</p></c>
        
        <c><p>p3</p></c>
        
        <c><p>p4</p></c>
</nod>

From this XML , I want to update name of 'nod' to 'newnod' and create an orderedlist for element 'c' ; so that output comes as:

 <newnod>
        
     <a>A</a> 
        
        <b>B</b>
        
        <orderedlist>
                            
        <listitem><p>p1</p></listitem>
                            
        <listitem><p>p2</p></listitem>
                            
        <listitem><p>p3</p></listitem>
                            
        <listitem><p>p4</p></listitem>
         </orderedlist>
</newnod>

Can anybody please tell me how to do this.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Do you want to transform all <c> elemnets, or do you want to transform all elements where count > 1  ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my solution that is entirely in "push style".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a true "push-style" solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/nod">
  <newnod>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </newnod>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c[1]">
  <orderedlist>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="wrap"
    select=".|following-sibling::c"/>
  </orderedlist>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c" mode="wrap">
  <listitem>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </listitem>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<nod>
 <a>A</a>
 <b>B</b>
 <c><p>p1</p></c>
 <c><p>p2</p></c>
 <c><p>p3</p></c>
 <c><p>p4</p></c>
</nod>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<newnod>
  <a>A</a>
  <b>B</b>
  <orderedlist>
    <listitem>
      <p>p1</p>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
      <p>p2</p>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
      <p>p3</p>
    </listitem>
    <listitem>
      <p>p4</p>
    </listitem>
  </orderedlist>
</newnod>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, a good solution, of course. There is just this problem that the OP implies the series of c* to be sorted (<orderedlist>), a requirement which cannot be reconciled with sibling recursion. Best, Michael

Comment: @Michael-Ludwig: Thank you for your comment. I think the name of the element (orderedlist) doesn't oblige the solver of the current problem to perform any sorting -- this is not asked for by the OP and the elements in the provided XML document are already sorted -- they just aren't marked as such -- and this marking/wrapping is the essence of the question.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I haven't looked at this kind of XSLT problem in a while, and your solution is an excellent reminder for me how clean XSLT code looks like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired output for your example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/nod">
    <newnod>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not( self::c )]"/>
      <orderedlist>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="c">
          <xsl:sort/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </orderedlist>
    </newnod>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nod/c">
    <listitem>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </listitem>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that it might need some tweaking for your actual input. For example, the details of sorting. Or the sequence of `a`, `b` and `c`. And lump all `c` together or not? But it works for your sample.

Comment: Hi Michael, as you said, it works for this sample. But in case, there is another element <d> after all <c> elements, then the element <d> in the output is tagged before the list.Can you please advice, what should I do in this case.

Comment: In that case, you need to tell whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? With 1.0, you'd resort to sibling recursion, whereas with 2.0 you'd use the grouping facility.

Comment: @Piyush: Check @Dimitre's answer and mine for more general patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="nod">
    <newnod>
        <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <orderedlist>
            <xsl:for-each select="c">
                <listitem><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></listitem>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </orderedlist>
    </newnod>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach is traversing the following axis like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nod">
        <newnod>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </newnod>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c">
        <orderedlist>
            <xsl:call-template name="wrap"/>
        </orderedlist>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"
                             mode="search"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c" name="wrap" mode="wrap">
        <listitem>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </listitem>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"
                             mode="wrap"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="wrap"/>
    <xsl:template match="c" mode="search">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"
                             mode="search"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="search">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or shorter (more "push style"):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nod">
        <newnod>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </newnod>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c">
        <orderedlist>
            <xsl:call-template name="wrap"/>
        </orderedlist>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                        [not(self::c)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c" name="wrap" mode="wrap">
        <listitem>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </listitem>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]
                                        /self::c"
                             mode="wrap"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both output:

```
<newnod>
    <a>A</a>
    <b>B</b>
    <orderedlist>
        <listitem>
            <p>p1</p>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <p>p2</p>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <p>p3</p>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <p>p4</p>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
</newnod>
```

**Note**: Even with XSLT 2.0, some complex sequence processing are expressed better with this pattern.